# Navigate though work spaces just like Mac using mouse gestures in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, workspace, navigation

I tried using [**easystroke**](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/easystroke/), but it didn't work out to the expected level. Are there any other ways to achieve this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Gestikk](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/gestikk-mouse-gesture-recognition-in-ubuntu.html).  You can also try [compiz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiz).  Look for the Scale plugin config window.